# Android SQLite Where Clause not considered

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I created a parametric query to get some data from the database table. Everything works, but the `AND tipo = 2` is not considered. Do you have suggestions?

```
 String sql = "SELECT titolo, icona, colore, tipo, identificativo, dato_campo FROM table " +
            "WHERE titolo LIKE '%" + parametro + "%' " +
            "OR dato_campo LIKE '%" + parametro + "%' AND tipo = 2 GROUP BY identificativo ORDER BY titolo ASC";
```

Comment: Do you only want "dato_campo" items if their "tipo = 2" or do you want every item retrieved to have "tipo = 2"?

Comment: Don't you forgot some parenthesis or do you really meant "a or b and c" ? (which is : a or (b and c ))

Comment: @DeeV I want every item retrieved to have "tipo = 2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets:

```
SELECT titolo, icona, colore, tipo,
    identificativo, dato_campo 
FROM table
WHERE 
    (titolo LIKE '%" + parametro + "%' " 
       OR 
      dato_campo 
            LIKE '%" + parametro + "%' 
   ) 
  AND tipo = 2 
GROUP BY identificativo ORDER BY titolo ASC";
```